Science fiction comic with a story about a robot orphanage that had a real human boy in it, and another about a man and woman who crash on a planet
They were groups of science fiction stories.
One story I remember was about a robot orphanage that had a real human boy in it who gets dismembered. Another was about a man and woman who crash on a planet; the man goes caveman mode and won't let the woman leave.

In roughly which year did you read this?

Are you looking for a collection of short stories in comic form (like a graphic novel?) or are these stories from separate volumes?  More information would be helpful.  When did you encounter them?  Any idea when they were written?  What the cover might have looked like?
